# Mujoco: Can I add a Label to Objects in the Scence?

Tags: python, mujoco

I am using the mujoco python wrapper in a project.
I would like to dynamically add and change text labels to objects in the scene that are displayed beside them in the final rendering.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

PS:I couldn't find any documentation.

Answer (score -1):

You mean like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ORsj_E17B0&t=140s)?

You can turn on the visualisation of various labels using the `label` [enum](https://mujoco.readthedocs.io/en/latest/APIreference/APItypes.html#mjtlabel) in [mjvOption](https://mujoco.readthedocs.io/en/latest/APIreference/APItypes.html#mjvoption).

Check out the MuJoCo Python [tutorial](https://mujoco.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python.html#tutorial-notebook) to see how to pass visual options to the render call.